# MySQL Query giving an error (1064)

Tags: mysql

Well, I'm trying to join two of my tables using inner join. This is the query I'm running:

```
select * from online_booking.Booking_ID, movie_schedule.Movie_ID, online_booking.Customer_Name, online_booking.Customer_Cell_No, online_booking.Quantity_Of_Tickets 
from movie_schedule
inner join online_booking
on movie_schedule.Movie_ID=online_booking.Movie_ID
```

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie_schedule` (
  `Movie_ID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Movie_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_Date` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Show_Time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_Cost` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Tickets_Availability` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Movie_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `online_booking` (
  `Booking_ID` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Quantity_Of_Tickets` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Cell_No` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_ID` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Booking_ID`),
  KEY `Movie_ID` (`Movie_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=114 ;

ALTER TABLE `online_booking`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `online_booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Movie_ID`) REFERENCES `movie_schedule` (`Movie_ID`);
```

To my surprise, I'm getting the following error:

**Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from movie_schedule
inner join online_booking
on movie_schedule.Movie_ID=online_' at line 2
(0 ms taken)**

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check where from you are selecting. The join query should be named and then select from that named table.

Comment: close vote, typo, you have `from` twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the field list after from,

Please change `select * from <field list>` to `select <field list> from` like so:

```
select online_booking.Booking_ID, movie_schedule.Movie_ID, online_booking.Customer_Name, online_booking.Customer_Cell_No, online_booking.Quantity_Of_Tickets 
from movie_schedule
inner join online_booking
on movie_schedule.Movie_ID=online_booking.Movie_ID
```

Comment: Silly me, that helped actually. By the way can I use derived attributes like: (online_booking.Quantity_Of_Tickets*movie_schedule.Movie_Cost) as Total_Amount. Will that work?

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped please ;)

Comment: I'm trying to get Quantity of Tickets from online booking table to multiply with the movie cost from movie schedule table so I that I can get the total amount displayed for each record. For that will the above query work like:
select (online_booking.Quantity_Of_Tickets*movie_schedule.Movie_Cost) as Total_Amount
from movie_schedule
inner join online_booking
on movie_schedule.Movie_ID=online_booking.Movie_ID

Comment: Your answer helped but because of this time rule thing I wasn't allowed to accept your answer before 10 minutes. Now there you go!

Comment: cool, forgot the rule, thanks, as for the other question I think it will work, but not quite sure as I don't know which data you have.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help. :)